How to batch combine PDF/JPEG files based on file name/sequential number
Good day all,
I am seeking a solution to batch combine thousands of PDF/JPEG files into sets based on filename and page number.  In the below sample, the goal would be to end with two files named 0001.pdf and 0002.pdf and their respective pages included in order.
Sample folder:
0001.jpg, 0001_Page_1.jpg, 0001_Page_2.jpg, 0001_Page_3.jpg, 0002.jpg, 0002_Page_1.jpg, 0002_Page_2.jpg, 0002_Page_3.jpg, 0002_Page_4.jpg, ect.
I've searched for quite awhile but can't seem to find a solution to match my needs.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

All are files are sized to letter so no adjustments needed beforehand.  I could use Acrobat to batch convert all JPGs to PDF before but was trying to save a step.  What I'm ultimately in search of is a means to batch combine the files based on their names with all "page_#" files added into them sequentially.  EDIT* All files are properly numbered so numbering won't be an issue.

Let me first say thank you for the responses as I neglected to do that previously.  Numbers can go up into the hundreds but they are always named page 0001, 0002 etc.

Thanks again for looking at it, I'll play around and see what I can come up with.

In your example, with the sample folder and the file 0001.jpg, I'm wondering—does 0001.pdf represent a folder (...\0001.jpg\ ) containing additional pages, or is it a single-page PDF where 0001.jpg serves as, say, a "cover" or the "first page" in a sequence?

I ended up finding and purchasing a premade solution called AutoSplit that perfectly does what I was trying to achieve.  Thanks again for your input and to answer your question, there is a base file then a the first numbered page file (0001) and each file is a single page jpg/pdf.

Note 1. It's not very clear whether the folder names are something like:
..\0001.jpg
..\0002.jpg
..\0004.jpg
and so on


Note 2. Also, for the file naming format after the underscore and "Page" (...._Page_X), are the files at this specific point zero-padded (...._Page_000X) or not?"

So, I am considering the following scenario for folder names and their .jpg file names, where the layout for the paths, folder names, and the names and extensions of their .jpg files is presented in the format illustrated below:
..\0001.jpg
..\0002.jpg
..\0004.jpg
and so on.

The files are not zero-padded after ...Page, so the paths would be:
..\0001.jpg\0001_Page_1.pdf
..\0001.jpg\0001_Page_2.pdf
..\0001.jpg\0001_Page_3.pdf
...
..\0002.jpg\0001_Page_1.pdf
..\0002.jpg\0001_Page_2.pdf
..\0002.jpg\0001_Page_3.pdf
...

Regardless of whether your files are zero-padded after Page_, you can use these loops to convert each file one by one in a loop:
@echo off && cd /d "%~dp0"

set "_magick=C:\Program Files\ImageMagick\magick.exe"
set "_flag_magick=-resize 2550x3300 -gravity center -extent 2550x3300 -density 300"

for /f ^usebackq^ ^delims^= %%i in =;(` dir /a:-a /b ".\*.jpg" ^| findstr /ie .*[0-9]\.jpg
    `);= do for /f ^usebackq^ ^tokens^=^1^-2*^ ^delims^=^_ %%I in =;(` dir /a:-d /b "%%~dpnxi\*.jpg"
        `);= do "%_magick%" "%%~fi\%%~nxI_%%~nJ_%%~nK.jpg" %_flag_magick% "%%~fi\%%~nxI_%%~nJ_%%~nK.pdf"

endlocal & goto :eof


Since you have numbered folders and the pages are also numbered, at some point you will concatenate the files arranged in your numbered folders and generate a PDF with all the pages concatenated into a single file, for example:
Magick.exe "D:\0001.jpg\*.pdf" "D:\0001.jpg\Output_All_0001.pdf"

For this purpose, commands that possibly use *.pdf with some concatenator may fail if the files are not in proper numerical sequence. Without leading zeros in .*.Page_X.pdf, the sorting will not follow the order 1, 2, 3... 9, but instead will follow the order:
..\0001_Page_1.jpg
..\0001_Page_10.jpg
..\0001_Page_11.jpg
..\0001_Page_12.jpg
..\0001_Page_13.jpg
..\0001_Page_14.jpg
..\0001_Page_15.jpg
..\0001_Page_16.jpg
..\0001_Page_17.jpg
..\0001_Page_18.jpg
..\0001_Page_19.jpg
..\0001_Page_2.jpg
..\0001_Page_20.jpg
..\0001_Page_21.jpg
..\0001_Page_22.jpg
..\0001_Page_23.jpg
..\0001_Page_24.jpg
..\0001_Page_25.jpg
..\0001_Page_26.jpg
..\0001_Page_27.jpg
..\0001_Page_28.jpg
..\0001_Page_29.jpg
..\0001_Page_3.jpg
..\0001_Page_30.jpg
..\0001_Page_4.jpg
..\0001_Page_5.jpg
..\0001_Page_6.jpg
..\0001_Page_7.jpg
..\0001_Page_8.jpg
..\0001_Page_9.jpg


Therefore, understand that if these are your future actions, there is a need to rename the files to ensure they are in the correct order, allowing you to have the pages numbered according to the expected sorting.
This is specifically for cases where your files do not have leading zeros; the code below will appropriately rename them for you, adding leading zeros in the format 0001_Page_000X.jpg and, after renaming them, will perform the conversion to .pdf for you.
@echo off && cd /d "%~dp0"

set "_magick=C:\Program Files\ImageMagick\magick.exe"
set "_flag_mgk=-resize 2550x3300 -gravity center -extent 2550x3300 -density 300"

for /f ^usebackq^ ^delims^= %%i in =;(` dir /a:-a /b ".\*.jpg" ^| findstr /ie .*[0-9]\.jpg 
   `);= do for /f ^usebackq^ ^tokens^=^1^-2^*^ ^delims^=^_ %%I in =;(`  dir /a:-d /b "%%~dpnxi\*.jpg" `);= do =;(
       set "_n=000%%~nK" 
       call ren "%%~fi\%%~nxI_%%~nJ_%%~nK.jpg" "%%~nxI_%%~nJ_%%_n:~-4%%.jpg"
       call "%_magick%" "%%~fi\%%~nxI_%%~nJ_%%_n:~-4%%.jpg" %_flag_mgk% "%%~fi\%%~nxI_%%~nJ_%%_n:~-4%%.pdf"
      );=

endlocal


After renaming the files, you can view them listed in a for loop, with the dir command, or another command; even when using the wildcard "*", the listing order will be perfectly aligned with the pagination order.

.\0001_Page_0001.jpg
.\0001_Page_0002.jpg
.\0001_Page_0003.jpg
.\0001_Page_0004.jpg
.\0001_Page_0005.jpg
.\0001_Page_0006.jpg
.\0001_Page_0007.jpg
.\0001_Page_0008.jpg
.\0001_Page_0009.jpg
.\0001_Page_0010.jpg
.\0001_Page_0011.jpg
.\0001_Page_0012.jpg
.\0001_Page_0013.jpg
.\0001_Page_0014.jpg
.\0001_Page_0015.jpg
.\0001_Page_0016.jpg
.\0001_Page_0017.jpg
.\0001_Page_0018.jpg
.\0001_Page_0019.jpg
.\0001_Page_0020.jpg
.\0001_Page_0021.jpg
.\0001_Page_0022.jpg
.\0001_Page_0023.jpg
.\0001_Page_0024.jpg
.\0001_Page_0025.jpg
.\0001_Page_0026.jpg
.\0001_Page_0027.jpg
.\0001_Page_0028.jpg
.\0001_Page_0029.jpg
.\0001_Page_0030.jpg


Note 3. Although you have found and purchased a solution (which I imagine uses a GUI), and understanding the multiple possibilities for script editing and adaptation, I decided to continue with the editing and posting to make this solution accessible to anyone interested who is looking for alternatives in a similar scenario.


Additional resources:

CD /?

Set /?

For /?

For /F /?

For /L /?

Find /?

Findstr /?

Using: Commands with Redirection

|, <, >, 2>, 2>&1, etc


Set variable=variable:substrings | DOS - String Manipulation

An A-Z Index of Windows CMD commands on ss64.com

How does the Windows Command Interpreter [cmd.exe] Parse Scripts


